# Run exec command on php

Tags: php, c, gcc, exec

I'm trying to run exec() from my php file.

From cmd I'm typing this: `gcc sample.c -o sample2.`

`Sample.c` is located in the same directory with my php file.
How could i do the same from php exec;

---

it works by putting full path of gcc: exec('C:\MinGW\bin\gcc sample.c -o str1', $output, $return);

the same thing with cmd i just type gcc , not full path.
why is this happening?

Comment: I happens because of environment PATH configuration. 
You can check value of the the variable running "phpinfo();"  (Environment > PATH)
The solution would be of these:
1. it should include C:\MinGW\bin\
2.(or) you need to move gcc to a folder that already exists in the PATH configuration

Comment: I have no issue running the script because I use linux and my phpinfo > Environment > PATH has value " /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin". gcc is in one of the folders

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
chdir(__DIR__);
exec('gcc sample.c -o sample2', $output, $return); 
// Return will return non-zero upon an error 
if (!$return) { 
  echo "failed"; 
} else { 
  echo "executed"; 
} 
?>
```